# Dissmiss current View Controller back to MainView Controller App Getting Crash IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Hi in my I'm uploading the image from my device to server after uploading it has to go back to the main view controller but I'm getting some issues in the app. After uploading image to serve my app getting crash.

```
NSString *urlString = @"url";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init]autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] ;
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@data",returnString);
    [self temp];
    [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
    alertTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    **[self performSelector:@selector(dissMissViewController) withObject:self afterDelay:4.0f];**
```

Dismiss Code.

```
         - (void)dissMissViewController
     {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];}];

      }
```

I don't where I'm doing wrong please tell me how to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: The crash log will be useful in helping us answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to solve it without stack trace, but seems to be your showAlert method being invoked when it's target is deallocated.

You are calling [self dismissModalViewController:] and only then - showAlert.

If you VC is not retained somewhere, you'll get crash here.

Comment: @krivobotsky its working f9 first time if i upload second time its getting craching pls tell me how to resolveit

Answer (score 0):

If your `application` use `Navigation Controller` then

```
- (void)dissMissViewController {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

else if it does not use `Navigation Controller`

```
- (void)dissMissViewController {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for ur replays i resolved the issue by changing the time interval in alert view now its working f9. Here is the code.

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dissMissViewController) withObject:self afterDelay:4.0f];
     alertTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```